show the stata codes using latex platforms
I hope to show the Stata code in latex (MikTex or Texstudio). There is a package for Matlab commands. Is there a package for Stata codes? Thank you.

you can include any file using packages such as listings or minted or simply verbatim

Quarto markdown is used mainly for R, but in theory can list code of Stata  and many other languages  inside your text, and optionally run it,  and  optionally too, insert the output automatically in the PDF , via a LaTeX export.
